# Unable to instantiate SMS messages java.lang.RunTimeExeption

Tags: android, sms

I've got a little problem with my application. I need to instantiate incoming SMS messages and write text to the file. So I've got

```
package com.reciever;
    public class SmsBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
    {
        private static final String ACTION = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
        {
            String newFolder = "/Budgetmate";
            String newFolder1="/logs";
            String sms_from="";
            if (intent != null && intent.getAction() != null &&
                    ACTION.compareToIgnoreCase(intent.getAction()) == 0) {
                Object[] pduArray = (Object[]) intent.getExtras().get("pdus");
                SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pduArray.length];
                    for (int i = 0; i < pduArray.length; i++) {
                        messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pduArray[i]);
                    } 
                sms_from = messages[0].getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
               // if (sms_from.equalsIgnoreCase("900")) {
                    StringBuilder bodyText = new StringBuilder();
                    for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
                      bodyText.append(messages[i].getMessageBody());
                   // }
                    String body = bodyText.toString();
                    Intent mIntent = new Intent(context, SmsService.class);
                    mIntent.putExtra("sms_body", body);
                    context.startService(mIntent);

                String dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+newFolder+newFolder1;
                File logFile = new File(dir+File.separator+"sms_from.txt");
                   if (!logFile.exists())
                   {
                      try
                      {
                         logFile.createNewFile();
                      } 
                      catch (IOException e)
                      {
                         e.printStackTrace();
                      }
                   }
                   try
                   {
                      BufferedWriter buf = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(logFile, true)); 
                      buf.append(sms_from);
                      buf.newLine();
                      buf.append(body);
                      buf.close();
                   }
                   catch (IOException e)
                   {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                   }
                abortBroadcast();
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

and here is my Manifest

```
'<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.smsparser"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >




    <receiver android:name=".SmsBroadcastReceiver">  
                <intent-filter android:priority="100">
                    <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
            </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <activity

        android:name="com.smsparser.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

I put my MainActivity and Reciever to different packages, but it's still does not work and throw java.lang.RuntimeExeption. Unable to instantiate reciever from com.smsparser java.lang.ClassNotFoundExeption.

Can you help me with that please?

Comment: Could you also post the catlog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `<receiver android:name=".SmsBroadcastReceiver">`

to `<receiver android:name="com.reciever.SmsBroadcastReceiver">`

Comment: Thank you! That was very helpful. And I've got to say, that if you need it to work you also should put your receiver to the package that will have this structure [name of package with your mainactivity].[some new name].

Answer (score 1):

You got your package names mixed up.

Your receiver is in `com.reciever` (which is misspelled, by the way), but your manifest tells the system it's in `com.smsparseer.SmsBroadcastReceiver`.

You need to either fix your manifest, or better, move your Receiver into the same package as your manifest states.